# How to compile using gcc with an older version in centos 6.4 using gcc64

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, c++11

I need to compile plugins for nuke. Im using centos 6.4 with gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC). On my binary folder I only have gcc and g++. I cant put a different version at the makefile. And Nuke its compiled with 4.1.

I'm not an expert in linux neither GNU, but I had the idea, once you have the newer you can tell g++ to compile the project with a different version.
Something like:
MYCXX ?= g++-4.1
LINK ?= g++-4.1

Comment: A "good" Makefile will accept something like `make CC=gcc-4.1 CXX=g++4.1`. I have no idea what "Nuke" is, so I can't be more specific than this. Be aware that if it depends on a nearly-8-years outdated compiler, it might also depend on outdated libraries, and even on version-specific bugs. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using linux you have following options:

1. Use update-alternative command
   for example:

   update-alternatives --config gcc

   Note: i assume you have installed multiple version of gcc.
2. Or Commad

   CC="gcc-VERSION" make

Answer (score 0):

First you must install gcc 4.1 in your linux, and set its path to your PATH environment, just like this:

```
export PATH=gcc4.1-path:$PATH
```

This will make your default gcc to be gcc 4.1version. then make nuke directly.